# What is the difference between the two Marshmallow factory images for Nexus 5 (MRA58K and MRA58N)?

Tags: nexus-5, 6.0-marshmallow, factory-image

On the [official site from Google that contains factory images](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en#hammerhead) of Android Marshmallow, there are two options for the Nexus 5.  One is MRA58K and the other MRA58N.  What is the difference between these two?  Which one do I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MRA58K` is initial Marshmallow release. `MRA58N` is security update.

> Google has listed one of the most severe critical security
>   vulnerabilities that can allow remote code execution on an affected
>   device through various methods such as email, web browsing, and MMS
>   when processing media files.

[Source](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/google-releases-november-android-security-update-for-nexus-range-760670) with additional details.